# Why is wood opaque?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, material-science, dielectric, insulators

Glass does not allow the flow of electrons through it, is transparent, and has higher skin depth. Similarly, wood has no free electrons and higher skin depth, but still it is opaque. Why?

Comment: [Scientists Develop Transparent Wood](https://www.cbc.ca/radio/quirks/scientists-develop-transparent-wood-that-is-stronger-and-lighter-than-glass-1.5902739)

Comment: See [NileRed's video on transparent wood](https://youtu.be/uUU3jW7Y9Ak).

Comment: Glass is not transparent if you look at a slap thick enough.

Answer (score 16):

Wood is actually not opaque. Here is an image showing that light passes through wood.

[image: translucent wood]

Wood is highly scattering, meaning that light goes a very short distance through wood before abruptly changing direction. That is why translucent pieces of wood must be very thin, and why objects on the other side are not seen clearly.

The opaque appearance of large sections of wood is due to repeated scattering such that light does not pass through the entire piece. But wood appears to "glow" when properly illuminated precisely because it is scattering but not opaque.

Interesting, this same effect can be seen in other biological tissues. Here we see it in a human hand with a strong light source.

[image: translucent human]

Again, the glowing effect is due to light scattering. In human tissues there is a strong frequency dependence where the scattering distance of red light is substantially longer than for other wavelengths.

Comment: In most of the place I read that wood is opaque. I am sharing one such link below:https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/wood-is-an-example-of-an-opaque-object-a-true-b-class-11-physics-jee-main-5f93a5a5f231cf558a6eb305

Comment: @RickAndy You can see light through wood, as shown in the first image. Sorry, I cannot correct every misuse of words on the internet

Comment: As you say, thin wood is translucent. But all the thick wood I have seen is opaque. Wood does absorb some. Scattering makes the path through the wood longer, which means it will be just about entirely absorbed before it gets very far. You can see the same thing in paper vs cardboard.

Comment: Wood must also have a fairly high absorptivity, on top of having a high scattering coefficient, since it glows only very dimly when illuminated.

Comment: @gs certainly. This is a continuum type of property. Human tissue is similar. The point is that the mean scattering path length is much shorter than the mean absorption path length. Not that the absorption path length is infinite.

Comment: There's a process to make a transparent wood composite by removing the lignin:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_wood_composite

Comment: Glass absorbs a bit of light too; if you have a slab of glass that's thick enough, it'll look opaque too.

Answer (score 2):

Wood scatters light due to tube-like cellulose fibers and absorbs it due to lignin. The absorption here occurs due to transitions between molecular states, rather than free electrons. By modifying these components it is possible to create a transparent wood, [Conversation Article on Transparent Wood](https://theconversation.com/transparent-wood-is-coming-and-it-could-make-an-energy-efficient-alternative-to-glass-154981).

Answer (score 0):

Wood is not actually opaque. **It's just opaque for our visible electromagnetic spectrum**. Light emerges even from the other side of the wood but it doesn't lie in our visible electromagnetic spectrum. But in the case of glass when it emerges from other side it lie in our visible electromagnetic spectrum so we call glass to be transparent but in case of wood the light which emerges from other side lies outside of a visible electromagnetic spectrum so we call as wood to be opaque.